# HTML - How to force a video wrapper to autoresize to the page layout

Tags: html, video, shopify

I have an autoplaying HTML video wrapper element on my shopify page that refuses to auto-scale to the page width. You can see the page here ([www.filmmaker-cinematics.com](http://www.filmmaker-cinematics.com)), as you can see the two video elements appear massively out of proportion on screen.

The whole site is built using a pre-coded design theme (shopify) and I've added these elements in as added part of a "rich text" element on the page that allows HTML code. So, all of the margins / page widths etc are pre-programmed and this video should scale automatically to fit. But it isn't playing ball.

The code I'm using for the video wrapper is as follows:

```
<div class="video-wrapper"><video autoplay="autoplay" muted="" loop="loop" playsinline="" preload="metadata">
  <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0522/8861/8684/files/EYES.mp4?v=1610122059" type="video/mp4" /></video></div>
```

Its important I keep this code the same as its the only I've found that allows autoplay on both desktop and mobile, which is important to the page design.

I'm certain there's some simple "max-width" code I can add, but nothing I seem to try works. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this website [Link](http://embedresponsively.com/) to generate flexible embed code that adjusts according to device width.

Comment: Note: the `<source>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Some .css has to be fixed, in particular, you have to assign `width: 100%;` to the `<video>` element inside the `.video-wrapper`.

The `.video-wrapper` was created to set an aspect-ratio on the `<video>` element, you can reference [this](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) article for more.

The `.video-wrapper` has the `padding-bottom` set to give the aspect ratio and the `padding-top: 25px` set and in this case, it is used as a `margin-top` which is incorrect.

We need to find the file where these properties are defined and correct them or overwrite them.

[Watch this code for solution - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umbertofontanazza/zLp26wtc/6/)

I'll give you an easy copy/paste fix which will do but it's not following best practices since CSS code inside `<style></style>` tags is not the best solution. (The best solution would be to find the .css file inside the assets folder of the theme but if you are not experienced you risk breaking things).

**Easy fix**

To fix this the easy way we're gonna overwrite the existing styles... I assume you are using some kind of page builder that lets you add HTML snippets, so you have to **add another HTML snippet** and **paste the following code**

```html
<style>
.pages-content .video-wrapper {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: calc(600/1920*100%);
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.video-wrapper video {
  width: 100%;
}</style>
```

What my code does is:

1. Define `width: 100%;` for the video element.
2. Remove `padding-top: 25px;` for the `.video-wrapper` and use `margin-top: 25px;` instead.
3. Chance the `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` on the `.video-wrapper` to `padding-bottom: calc(600/1920*100%);` where I used the width and height of your video 1920x600px.